# Scrapy : storing the data

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new with python and scrapy. I'm tring to follow the Scrapy tutorial but I don't understand the logic of the [storage step](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-storage-backends).

```
scrapy crawl spidername -o items.json -t json

scrapy crawl spidername --set FEED_URI=output.csv --set FEED_FORMAT=csv
```

I dont understand the signification of :

- -o
- -t
- --set

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can view a list of available commands by typing `scrapy crawl -h` from within your project directory.

```
scrapy crawl spidername -o items.json -t json
```

- `-o` specifies the output filename for dumped items (items.json)
- `-t` specifies the format for dumping items (json)

`scrapy crawl spidername --set FEED_URI=output.csv --set FEED_FORMAT=csv`

- `--set` is used to set/override a setting
- `FEED_URI` is used to set the storage backend for the item dumping. In this instance it is set to "output.csv" which is using the local filesystem ie a simple output file.(for current example - output.csv)
- `FEED_FORMAT` is used to set the serialization format for the (output) feed ie (for current example csv)

**References (Scrapy documentation):**

1. [Available tool commands (for the command line)](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html?highlight=command%20line#available-tool-commands)
2. [Feed exports](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html)

Comment: So the two lines are equivalents if ine the first one, I change `item.json` into `output.csv` and `json` into `csv` ?

Comment: That is correct. Alternatively you can add FEED_URI and FEED_FORMAT to your settings.py file and then just type 'scrapy crawl spidername' without the other parameters.

Comment: Please accept this answer if it covers the questions asked, or let me know if there's anything I can do to improve the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

**--set**

Arguments provided by the command line are the ones that take precedence, overriding any other options.

You can explicitly override one (or more) settings using the -s (or --set) command line option.

```
Example:

    scrapy crawl myspider -s LOG_FILE=scrapy.log

    sets the LOG_FILE settings value to `scrapy.log`
```

**-o**

Specifies the output filename and extension *WHERE* you will write the scraped data to

```
Examples: 
    scrapy crawl quotes -o items.csv
    scrapy crawl quotes -o items.json
    scrapy crawl quotes -o items.xml
```

**-t**

Specifies the serialisation format or *HOW* the items are written

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scrapy/scrapy_settings.htm