# Why my Scrapy project stop scraping, but still scrawling website well

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to collect data from stox.vn. I have urls.txt with have about 800 url, and pass all url to my bot. However, at first it crawl and scrape well. but then it's stop scrape and only crawl.

```
2013-06-27 03:24:28+0700 [stox] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://companyaz.stox.vn/Financial/PV_Index?filter=1&unit=1000000&ticker=AAA> (referer: http://companyaz.stox.vn/Financial?cId=746&iId=150&iIdL=147&eId=1&tId=2status=1&id=-1&cat=&ticker=AAA)
2013-06-27 03:24:28+0700 [stox] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://companyaz.stox.vn/Financial/PV_Index?filter=1&unit=1000000&ticker=AAA>

    {'chi_phi_ban_hang': u'-7453.41',
     'chi_phi_khau_hao_TSCD': u'11890.11',
     'chi_phi_quan_ly': u'-5913.60',
     'chi_phi_tai_chinh': u'-10677.99',
     'chi_phi_tien_lai_vay': u'-5672.17',
     'doanh_thu_thuan': u'122008.75',
     'gia_von_hang_ban': u'-90790.07',
     'lai_co_dong_ct_me': u'11885.60',
     'lai_gop': u'31218.69',
     'lai_sau_thue': u'11885.60',
     'lai_tu_hdkd': u'11376.31',
     'loi_ich_CDTS': u'11885.60',
     'qtime': u'20101',
     'thu_nhap_tai_chinh': u'4202.63',
     'thue_TNDN_hl': u'509.29',
     'thue_TNDN_ht': u'0',
     'ticker': 'AAA'}
.....
2013-06-27 03:24:31+0700 [stox] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://companyaz.stox.vn/Financial?cId=446&iId=292&iIdL=280&eId=3&tId=3status=1&id=-1&cat=&ticker=ABI> (referer: None)
2013-06-27 03:24:33+0700 [stox] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://companyaz.stox.vn/Financial?cId=1&iId=217&iIdL=202&eId=0&tId=2status=1&id=-1&cat=&ticker=ABT> (referer: None)
2013-06-27 03:24:36+0700 [stox] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://companyaz.stox.vn/Financial?cId=164&iId=289&iIdL=279&eId=1&tId=0status=1&id=-1&cat=&ticker=ACB> (referer: None)
2013-06-27 03:24:38+0700 [stox] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://companyaz.stox.vn/Financial?cId=522&iId=180&iIdL=170&eId=0&tId=2status=1&id=-1&cat=&ticker=ACC> (referer: None)
2013-06-27 03:24:40+0700 [stox] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://companyaz.stox.vn/Financial?cId=486&iId=180&iIdL=170&eId=3&tId=2status=1&id=-1&cat=&ticker=ACE> (referer: None)
2013-06-27 03:24:42+0700 [stox] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://companyaz.stox.vn/Financial?cId=2&iId=217&iIdL=202&eId=0&tId=2status=1&id=-1&cat=&ticker=ACL> (referer: None)
2013-06-27 03:24:44+0700 [stox] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://companyaz.stox.vn/Financial?cId=858&iId=256&iIdL=241&eId=1&tId=2status=1&id=-1&cat=&ticker=ADC> (referer: None)
2013-06-27 03:24:47+0700 [stox] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://companyaz.stox.vn/Financial?cId=556&iId=180&iIdL=170&eId=3&tId=2status=1&id=-1&cat=&ticker=ADP> (referer: None)
```

Here what i'm doing 
In stox/spider/test.py

```
from scrapy import log
import logging
from scrapy.log import ScrapyFileLogObserver
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from stox.items import StoxItem
from scrapy.http import Request, Response
from scrapy.http.cookies import CookieJar
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "stox"
    allowed_domains = ["stox.vn"]    
    start_urls =["http://companyaz.stox.vn/Financial?cId=113&iId=217&iIdL=202&eId=0&tId=2&status=1&id=-1&cats=&ticker=FPT",
        "http://companyaz.stox.vn/Financial?cId=113&iId=217&iIdL=202&eId=0&tId=2&status=1&id=-1&cats=&ticker=SSC"]    
    ticker = "";
    items = [];

    def __init__(self):
        #write log file here
        logfile = open('testlog.log', 'w')
        log_observer = ScrapyFileLogObserver(logfile, level=logging.DEBUG)
        log_observer.start() #start logging

    def start_requests(self):
        products = []
        #with open('urls.txt', 'rb') as urls:
        #    for url in urls:
        #        yield Request(url, self.parse)

        # extract url file and call parse()
        f = open("urls.txt")
        start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
        f.close()
        for url in start_urls:
            yield Request(url, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):


        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)        
        self.ticker = "".join(hxs.select("//div[@class='stock-ticker-title']/label/text()").extract()).strip()

        my_start_url = "http://companyaz.stox.vn/Financial/PV_Index?filter=1&unit=1000000&ticker=%s" % self.ticker

        #get the cookie of start_url
        cookieJar = response.meta.setdefault('cookie_jar', CookieJar())
        cookieJar.extract_cookies(response, response.request)

        request = Request(my_start_url, callback = self.extractItem,
                          meta = {'dont_merge_cookies': True, 'cookie_jar': cookieJar})

        cookieJar.add_cookie_header(request) # apply Set-Cookie ourselves
        yield request        


    def extractItem(self, response):
        items = [];

        #extract ticker from url
        pos =  response.url.find('ticker=')
        l = len("ticker=")
        ticker = response.url[pos+l:]

        f = open("data/%s.csv" % ticker, 'w')

        #get the XPath        
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)        
        titles = hxs.select("//p[@data-time]/..")                
        for title in titles:
            item = StoxItem()
            item ["ticker"] = ticker;
            item ["qtime"] = "".join(title.select("./p/@data-time").extract())
            item ["doanh_thu_thuan"] = ''.join(title.select("./div[1]/p[1]/text()").extract()).strip().replace('.','').replace(',','.')
            item ["gia_von_hang_ban"] = ''.join(title.select("./div[1]/p[2]/text()").extract()).strip().replace('.','').replace(',','.')#.encode('utf-8')                        
            item ["lai_gop"] = ''.join(title.select("./div[2]/p[1]/text()").extract()).strip().replace('.','').replace(',','.')
            item ["thu_nhap_tai_chinh"] = ''.join(title.select("./div[2]/p[2]/text()").extract()).strip().replace('.','').replace(',','.')
            item ["chi_phi_tai_chinh"] = ''.join(title.select("./div[2]/p[3]/text()").extract()).strip().replace('.','').replace(',','.') 
            item ["chi_phi_tien_lai_vay"] = ''.join(title.select("./div[2]/p[4]/text()").extract()).strip().replace('.','').replace(',','.')
            item ["chi_phi_ban_hang"] = ''.join(title.select("./div[2]/p[5]/text()").extract()).strip().replace('.','').replace(',','.')
            item ["chi_phi_quan_ly"] = ''.join(title.select("./div[2]/p[6]/text()").extract()).strip().replace('.','').replace(',','.')
            item ["lai_tu_hdkd"] = ''.join(title.select("./div[3]/p[1]/text()").extract()).strip().replace('.','').replace(',','.')
            item ["thue_TNDN_ht"] = ''.join(title.select("./div[3]/p[2]/text()").extract()).strip().replace('.','').replace(',','.')
            item ["thue_TNDN_hl"] = ''.join(title.select("./div[3]/p[3]/text()").extract()).strip().replace('.','').replace(',','.')
            item ["lai_sau_thue"] = ''.join(title.select("./div[4]/p[1]/text()").extract()).strip().replace('.','').replace(',','.')
            item ["loi_ich_CDTS"] = ''.join(title.select("./div[4]/p[1]/text()").extract()).strip().replace('.','').replace(',','.')
            item ["lai_co_dong_ct_me"] = ''.join(title.select("./div[5]/p[1]/text()").extract()).strip().replace('.','').replace(',','.')
            item ["chi_phi_khau_hao_TSCD"] = ''.join(title.select("./div[6]/p[1]/text()").extract()).strip().replace('.','').replace(',','.')            
            items.append(item)

            #write to file
            str = "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" % (item ["ticker"],
                                                                            item ["qtime"],
                                                                            item ["doanh_thu_thuan"],
                                                                            item ["gia_von_hang_ban"],
                                                                            item ["lai_gop"],
                                                                            item ["thu_nhap_tai_chinh"],
                                                                            item ["chi_phi_tai_chinh"],
                                                                            item ["chi_phi_tien_lai_vay"],
                                                                            item ["chi_phi_ban_hang"],
                                                                            item ["chi_phi_quan_ly"],
                                                                            item ["lai_tu_hdkd"],
                                                                            item ["thue_TNDN_ht"],
                                                                            item ["thue_TNDN_hl"],
                                                                            item ["lai_sau_thue"],
                                                                            item ["loi_ich_CDTS"],
                                                                            item ["lai_co_dong_ct_me"],
                                                                            item ["chi_phi_khau_hao_TSCD"])
            f.write(str)

        #print "Item %r " %items;
        f.close()
        return items
```

My settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'stox'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['stox.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'stox.spiders'

# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'stox (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'
#ITEM_PIPELINES = ['stox.pipelines.StoxPipeline']
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2
#DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 180
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 2
```

I check that when I change the param CONCURRENT_REQUESTS, then it will stop after scrapes CONCURENT_REQUEST times, and then it only crawl. I think there is a problem with the Concurrent process (which it is not free the process??? )

**UPDATED**
The content of urls.txt

```
http://companyaz.stox.vn/Financial?cId=746&iId=150&iIdL=147&eId=1&tId=2status=1&id=-1&cat=&ticker=AAA
http://companyaz.stox.vn/Financial?cId=446&iId=292&iIdL=280&eId=3&tId=3status=1&id=-1&cat=&ticker=ABI
http://companyaz.stox.vn/Financial?cId=1&iId=217&iIdL=202&eId=0&tId=2status=1&id=-1&cat=&ticker=ABT
.....
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

PS: I'm very new to Scrapy project and sorry for my lack of english

Comment: What is the contents of `urls.txt`?

Comment: @alecxe: Sorry for answer late. The url I update already above. Its contents is list of 800 url.

Answer (score 0):

Out of your 800 url, you are writing with ticker name as the file.
Are the ticker names distinct in all urls? If they are not distinct, you might be overwriting the files. Instead of writing into a file, you can use the export option.

You can read the following thread to know about exporting the data.
[Scrapy : storing the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073442/scrapy-storing-the-data)